# how to parse a line from a process and use the result in a trap that will work?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a process `foo`. I want to run each line that foo outputs, trap a line of the form `command is <cmd>` (where  is some command that is different in each run) and then trap SIGKILL to run ''.

I try something like:

```
while read line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ command\ is\ (.*) ]]; then
    echo trapping
    trap "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" SIGKILL
  fi
done < <(foo)
```

I see 'trapping' being printed, but when I kill the script, the command is not issued.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. There are two signals which cannot be intercepted and handled: `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`

Comment: Yes `SIGINT` can be handled.